# What sauce could I use for haddock?

Tags: sauce, fish, haddock

I'm doing fish fries tonight, and my wife doesn't like breaded fish.
The thought was to pan sear hers and finish it with a sauce. Unfortunately, I'm having a tough time finding sauce ideas for haddock. What flavors/base would go well with haddock? I want to avoid tartar sauce for a pan seared fillet.

Comment: Well, turns out that the wife just didn't know what she was talking about, she enjoyed the battered haddock and I didn't have to spend additional time on a different method plus a sauce! http://www.flickr.com/photos/xerofun/6041167391

Comment: Voting to close because this question does not meet *current* standards:  it is an open ended "what goes with X" question.  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/should-we-close-questions-structured-like-what-compliments-does-not-work-with

Comment: Yep, as the accepted answer says, this list could be endless. Mild, white fish is even worse than a lot of cases; so many things go with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compound butter is a very nice accompaniment for fish.

"Compound butter is a mixture of softened butter and at least one other ingredient.  Some ideas for compound butter are: herbs, spices, citrus zest/juice, honey, fresh mint, soft cheeses (like goat), fresh or dried peppers, and nuts…you get the idea – this list could be endless!"

You can cook the fish on its own and then put the compound butter on top to melt over it. While soft the butter can be put into a piping bag and piped as rosettes and refrigerated until ready to use. Makes for a nice presentation.

Another common accompaniment to fish is mango salso or a combination of tropical fruits (mango pineapple for example).

This seemed like a good link for ideas for sauces for Haddock:

http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-different-types-of-sauce-for-haddock.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I've made compound butters before for steak, never thought to extend them to fish.

Answer (score 3):

If I was eating it, I'd simply squeeze some lemon juice over the fish on my plate. I've also had haddock with a white sauce or a cheese sauce. I'd suggest making a cheese sauce using philly cream cheese and some milk.

An alternative to pan seared would be to bake. There are lot of suggestions for baked haddock in google.

Comment: Simple is always best isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Mayonnaise, sweet mustard, curry powder and a dash of some salty seasoning. Blend and eat with rice. Roll the fish in wheat and spice with salt and lemon-pepper.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for your specific meal, but I've always found that mustard goes very well with fish. I usually do a roux using flour and butter, pour in some cream or milk to slightly thin it, and then add some hot mustard to it, and season with salt & pepper. To give it more texture and colour I add some coarse grain mustard if we've got it, but this isn't a must. Together with boiled potatoes and some lemon juice drizzled over the fish, I think it's delicious.